# How to order lines but keep legend order in Chart.js?

Tags: vue.js, charts, chart.js

How to order lines but keep legend order in Chart.js?
I am trying to repeat one chart which is written in chart.js. JS Framework: Vue.
I need the lines to be in front (see Fig. 1), and now I have this (see Fig. 2)
It is also important that the order of the legends is the same as in Fig. 1.
Also I tried chart.js built-in field "order" - I got the result, but the order of the legends is violated.
Fig.1
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcumZ.jpg)
Fig.2
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJ1Zw.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify what "the lines to be in front" means. What is the difference between these charts? The order is the same, as far as I can see, some of legend items flow to the second line, depending on chart width

Comment: I could use "order" option for the dataset to define the drawing order (see doc). For legend, have a look to sort option from the doc in the legend.labels

Comment: @user2057925, do You know any example for sorting legends?

Comment: here is a codepen, which is sorting the legends based on the max value of the dataset: https://codepen.io/stockinail/pen/ExdYRmZ